# Async Targeting Pack without Visual Studio 2012 on BuildServer

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, async-await, build-server

I am using a Buildserver which does not have installed any Visual Studio. I use TeamCity with msbuild Agent to Building my application. Now, I need to use the Async Targeting Pack for using async/await (I cannot update the application to .NET 4.5 because it has to run on Windows XP Machines).

Now, I am searching a way to continue build my application on this machine with Referenced the Async Targeting Pack but without installing Visual Studio 2012. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? How did that fail? Does build server have .Net 4.5 installed (I think it's required, because it contains the C# 5.0 compiler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aync Targeting Pack is now on NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

You could reference the package from your project which should make it runnable on your build server without installing the Visual Studio extension.