# Build error due to Async BCL packages without VS 2012 on a CI server (Team City)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.0, teamcity

I develop an application that has to run on Windows XP (so the .Net Framework has to be 4.0). I need to reference Async BCL packages in order to use async/await in some of my projects.

I have correctly referenced the following packages to the targeted projects as mentioned by ThomasArdal in his answer ([Async Targeting Pack without Visual Studio 2012 on BuildServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870081/async-targeting-pack-without-visual-studio-2012-on-buildserver)):

Microsoft.BCL

Microsoft.BCL.Async

Microsoft.BCL.Build

Unfortunately the build fails when it is run from TeamCity on my CI server (running Microsoft Windows Server 2003) because async/await keywords are not recognized:

```
Member modifier 'public' must precede the member type and name
```

Do you have any clue that could help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CI server must use the latest msbuild.exe (from .net 4.5)

Comment: My CI server runs on Windows server 2003. The .Net Framework 4.5 is not supported on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx

Comment: A better way to say it is msbuild from Visual Studio 2012, you can use the latest msbuild without the latest .NET.

Comment: Ok I moved to an other server which runs Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. I have installed the latest version of the Framework 4.5 on this machine (published on 10/9/2012) but now I get the following error: 'Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.YieldAwaitable.YieldAwaiter' does not implement 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion' which is supposed to happen in 4.0. My teamCity is configured to use the MSBuildVersion of the 4.5 Framework. Any clue ?

Comment: Found a solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730765/net-4-0-build-issues-on-ci-server